# Is there a non-atomic equivalent of std::shared_ptr? And why isn't there one in <memory>?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

This is a bit of a two part question, all about the atomicity of `std::shared_ptr`:

**1.**
As far as I can tell, `std::shared_ptr` is the only smart pointer in `<memory>` that's atomic. I'm wondering if there is a non-atomic version of `std::shared_ptr` available (I can't see anything in `<memory>`, so I'm also open to suggestions outside of the standard, like those in Boost). I know `boost::shared_ptr` is also atomic (if `BOOST_SP_DISABLE_THREADS` isn't defined), but maybe there's another alternative? I'm looking for something that has the same semantics as `std::shared_ptr`, but without the atomicity.

**2.** I understand why `std::shared_ptr` is atomic; it's kinda nice. However, it's not nice for every situation, and C++ has historically had the mantra of "only pay for what you use." If I'm not using multiple threads, or if I am using multiple threads but am not sharing pointer ownership across threads, an atomic smart pointer is overkill. My second question is *why wasn't a non-atomic version of `std::shared_ptr` provided in C++11*? (assuming there is a *why*) (if the answer is simply "a non-atomic version was simply never considered" or "no one ever asked for a non-atomic version" that's fine!).

With question #2, I'm wondering if someone ever proposed a non-atomic version of `shared_ptr` (either to Boost or the standards committee) (not to replace the atomic version of `shared_ptr`, but to coexist with it) and it was shot down for a specific reason.

Comment: What "cost" exactly are you concerned about here? The cost of atomically incrementing an integer? Is that actually a cost that concerns you for any real application? Or are you just prematurely optimizing?

Comment: @NicolBolas: It's more curiosity than anything else; I don't (currently) have any code/project where I'm seriously wanting to use a non-atomic shared pointer. However, I have had projects (in the past) where Boost's `shared_ptr` was a significant slowdown due to its atomicity, and defining `BOOST_DISABLE_THREADS` made a noticeable difference (I don't know if `std::shared_ptr` would have had the same cost that that `boost::shared_ptr` had).

Comment: @Close voters: what part of the question isn't constructive? If there isn't a specific *why* for the second question, that's fine (a simple "it simply wasn't considered" would be a valid enough answer). I'm curious *if there is* a specific reason/rationale that exists. And the first question certainly is a valid question, I'd say. If I need to clarify the question, or make slight adjustments to it, please let me know. But I don't see how it's not constructive.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _atomic_? There seems to be some inconsistency in your question. "As far as I can tell, `std::shared_ptr` is the only smart pointer in `<memory>` that's atomic." vs "why wasn't an atomic version of `std::shared_ptr` provided in C++11?".

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Gah, it was a typo. I meant "why wasn't a non-atomic version..." Thanks, I fixed it!

Comment: @Cornstalks Well, it's probably just that people don't react that well on questions they can easily dismiss as *"premature optimization"*, no matter how valid, well-posed or relevant the question is, I guess. I for myself don't see any reason to close this as non-constructive.

Comment: (can't write an answer now it's closed, so commenting) With GCC when your program doesn't use multiple threads `shared_ptr` doesn't use atomic ops for the refcount. See (2) at http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2007-10/msg00180.html for a patch to GCC to allow the non-atomic implementation to be used even in multithreaded apps, for `shared_ptr` objects that aren't shared between threads. I've been sitting on that patch for years but I'm considering finally committing it for GCC 4.9

Comment: @JonathanWakely: the question is open again, so if you want to add that comment as an answer (and perhaps add any further insights) I would certainly up-vote it :)

Comment: Agree with OP. We use shared_ptr's all over the place (i.e. as function argument; in for loops and return value) and the atomic ref count makes them non trivial to copy. Mostly they are located in the (single threaded) GUI part; only a small portion across threads. Use with (ugly) const reference partially circumvents the problem of copy.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

> 1.  I'm wondering if there is a non-atomic version of std::shared_ptr available

Not provided by the standard.  There may well be one provided by a "3rd party" library.  Indeed, prior to C++11, and prior to Boost, it seemed like everyone wrote their own reference counted smart pointer (including myself).

> 2. My second question is why wasn't a non-atomic version of std::shared_ptr provided in C++11?

This question was discussed at the Rapperswil meeting in 2010.  The subject was introduced by a National Body Comment #20 by Switzerland.  There were strong arguments on both sides of the debate, including those you provide in your question.  However, at the end of the discussion, the vote was overwhelmingly (but not unanimous) against adding an unsynchronized (non-atomic) version of `shared_ptr`.

Arguments against included:

- Code written with the unsynchronized shared_ptr may end up being used in threaded code down the road, ending up causing difficult to debug problems with no warning.
- Having one "universal" shared_ptr that is the "one way" to traffic in reference counting has benefits:  From [the original proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1431.htm):

  > Has the same object type regardless of features used, greatly facilitating interoperability between libraries, including third-party libraries.
- The cost of the atomics, while not zero, is not overwhelming.  The cost is mitigated by the use of move construction and move assignment which do not need to use atomic operations.  Such operations are commonly used in `vector<shared_ptr<T>>` erase and insert.
- Nothing prohibits people from writing their own non-atomic reference-counted smart pointer if that's really what they want to do.

The final word from the LWG in Rapperswil that day was:

> Reject CH 20. No consensus to make a change at this time.

Comment: Wow, perfect, thanks for the information! That's exactly the kind of information I was hoping to find.

Comment: > `Has the same object type regardless of features used, greatly facilitating interoperability between libraries, including third-party libraries.`

that's an extremely weird reasoning. Third party libraries will provide their own types anyways, so why would it matter if they provided it under the form of std::shared_ptr<CustomType>, std::non_atomic_shared_ptr<CustomType>, etc ? you will always have to adapt your code to what the library returns anyways

Comment: That's true as far as library-specific types go, but the idea is that there are also lots of places where standard types show up in third-party APIs. For example, my library might take a `std::shared_ptr<std::string>` somewhere. If someone else's library takes that type too, callers can pass the same strings to both of us without the inconvenience or overhead of converting between different representations, and that's a small win for everyone.

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier Also, imagine a library using `std::unsynchronized_shared_ptr` in its interface. You want to use the library, but your application happens to be multithreaded. You now have a pointer that you must protect with a mutex every time you pass it around.

Comment: @LukasBarth the alternative to `std::unsynchronized_shared_ptr` in the interface if the latter is not available is *not* `std::shared_ptr`, it's *let's use our own custom shared pointer type which does exactly what we want even if it needs explicit synchronisation* instead. Making things strictly worse for the end-user.

Comment: @LukasBarth Isn't that how it is supposed to be? For eg, all the containers in STL are unsynchronized, and you have to protect it with a mutex when you are using it in multiple threads.

Answer (score 62):

Howard's answered the question well already, and Nicol made some good points about the benefits of having a single standard shared pointer type, rather than lots of incompatible ones.

While I completely agree with the committee's decision, I do think there is some benefit to using an unsynchronized `shared_ptr`-like type *in special cases*, so I've investigated the topic a few times.

> If I'm not using multiple threads, or if I am using multiple threads but am not sharing pointer ownership across threads, an atomic smart pointer is overkill.

With GCC when your program doesn't use multiple threads shared_ptr doesn't use atomic ops for the refcount.  This is done by updating the reference counts via wrapper functions that detect whether the program is multithreaded (on GNU/Linux this is done by checking a special variable in Glibc that says if the program is single-threaded<sup>[1]</sup>) and dispatch to atomic or non-atomic operations accordingly.

I realised many years ago that because GCC's `shared_ptr<T>` is implemented in terms of a [`__shared_ptr<T, _LockPolicy>` base class](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/memory.html#std.util.memory.shared_ptr), it's possible to use the base class with the single-threaded locking policy even in multithreaded code, by explicitly using `__shared_ptr<T, __gnu_cxx::_S_single>`. You can use an alias template like this to define a shared pointer type that is not thread-safe, but is slightly faster<sup>[2]</sup>:

```
template<typename T>
  using shared_ptr_unsynchronized = std::__shared_ptr<T, __gnu_cxx::_S_single>;
```

This type would not be interoperable with `std::shared_ptr<T>` and would only be safe to use when it is guaranteed that the `shared_ptr_unsynchronized` objects would never be shared between threads without additional user-provided synchronization.

This is of course completely non-portable, but sometimes that's OK. With the right preprocessor hacks your code would still work fine with other implementations if `shared_ptr_unsynchronized<T>` is an alias for `shared_ptr<T>`, it would just be a little faster with GCC.

---

<sub>[1] Before Glibc 2.33 added that variable, the wrapper functions would detect whether the program links to `libpthread.so` as an imperfect method of checking for single-threaded vs multi-threaded.</sub>

<sub>[2] Unfortunately because that wasn't an intended use case it didn't quite work optimally before GCC 4.9, and some operations still used the wrapper functions and so dispatched to atomic operations even though you've explicitly requested the `_S_single` policy. See point (2) at http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2007-10/msg00180.html for more details and a patch to GCC to allow the non-atomic implementation to be used even in multithreaded apps.  I sat on that patch for years but I finally committed it for GCC 4.9.</sub>

Comment: Just wondering, is there a typo in your example of the template alias? I.e. I think it should read shared_ptr_unsynchronized = std::__shared_ptr<. Incidentally, I tested this today, in conjunction with std::__enable_shared_from_this and std::__weak_ptr, and it seems to work nicely (gcc 4.9 and gcc 5.2). I will profile/disassemble it shortly to see if indeed the atomic operations are skipped.

Comment: Awesome details! Recently I faced an issue, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47202468/segfault-on-declaring-a-variable-of-type-vectorshared-ptrint), that eventually made me to look into the source code of `std::shared_ptr`, `std::__shared_ptr`, `__default_lock_policy` and such. This answer confirmed what I understood from the code.

Answer (score 20):

> My second question is why wasn't a non-atomic version of std::shared_ptr provided in C++11? (assuming there is a why).

One could just as easily ask why there isn't an intrusive pointer, or any number of other possible variations of shared pointers one could have.

The design of `shared_ptr`, handed down from Boost, has been to create a minimum standard lingua-franca of smart pointers. That, generally speaking, you can just pull this down off the wall and use it. It's something that would be used generally, across a wide variety of applications. You can put it in an interface, and odds are good people will be willing to use it.

Threading is only going to get *more* prevalent in the future. Indeed, as time passes, threading will generally be one of the primary means to achieve performance. Requiring the basic smart pointer to do the bare minimum needed to support threading facilitates this reality.

Dumping a half-dozen smart pointers with minor variations between them into the standard, or even worse a policy-based smart pointer, would have been terrible. Everyone would pick the pointer they like best and forswear all others. Nobody would be able to communicate with anyone else. It'd be like the current situations with C++ strings, where everyone has their own type. Only far worse, because interoperation with strings is a lot easier than interoperation between smart pointer classes.

Boost, and by extension the committee, picked a specific smart pointer to use. It provided a good balance of features and was widely and commonly used in practice.

`std::vector` has some inefficiencies compared to naked arrays in some corner cases too. It has some limitations; some uses really want to have a hard limit on the size of a `vector`, without using a throwing allocator. However, the committee didn't design `vector` to be everything for everyone. It was designed to be a good default for most applications. Those for whom it can't work can just write an alternative that suites their needs.

Just as you can for a smart pointer if `shared_ptr`'s atomicity is a burden. Then again, one might also consider not copying them around so much.

Comment: +1 for "one might also consider not copying them around so much."

Comment: If you ever hook up a profiler, you're special and you can just tune out arguments like the above. If you don't have an operational requirement that is hard to meet you shouldn't use C++. Arguing like you do is a good way to make C++ universally reviled by anyone interested in high performance or low latency.This is why game programmers don't use STL, boost or even exceptions.

Comment: For clarity, I think the quote at the top of your answer should read "why wasn't *a non-atomic* version of std::shared_ptr provided in C++11?"

Answer (score 9):

Boost provides a `shared_ptr` that's non-atomic. It's called [`local_shared_ptr`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/smart_ptr/doc/html/smart_ptr.html#local_shared_ptr), and can be found in the smart pointers library of boost.

Comment: +1 for a short solid reply with good citation, but this pointer type looks costly - in terms of both memory and runtime, due to one extra level of indirection( local->shared->ptr vs shared->ptr).

Comment: @Red.Wave Can you explain what you mean with indirection and how it affects performance? Do you mean that it's a `shared_ptr` with a counter anyway, even though it's local? Or do you mean there's another problem with it? The docs say that the *only* difference is that this is not atomic.

Comment: Every local ptr keeps a count and refrence to the original shared ptr. Thus any access to to the final pointee needs a derefrence from local to shared ptr, which is then derefrence to the pointee. Thus there is one more indirection stacked up to the indirections from shared ptr. And that increases overhead.

Comment: @Red.Wave Where are you getting this information from? This: "Thus any access to to the final pointee needs a derefrence from local to shared ptr" needs some citation. I couldn't find that in boost docs. Again, what I saw in the docs is that it says that `local_shared_ptr` and `shared_ptr` are identical except for atomic. I'm genuinely interested in finding out whether what you're saying is true because I use `local_shared_ptr` in applications that require high performance.

Comment: That is what the doc says. In terms of reference counting there must be an advantage, but in terms of memory it is obviously less efficient and access to pointee seems to have time penalty(twice indirection/ derefrence), or the memory overhead is even more.

Comment: @Red.Wave Can you please quote the part of the docs that says that? I can't find it.

Comment: "One can think of local_shared_ptr<T> as shared_ptr<shared_ptr<T>>, with the outer shared_ptr using non-atomic operations for its count. Converting from local_shared_ptr to shared_ptr gives you a copy of the inner shared_ptr; converting from shared_ptr wraps it into an outer shared_ptr with a non-atomic use count (conceptually speaking) and returns the result."

Comment: Paragraph 2 after example code 11. That just means two levels of indirection/derefrencing.

Comment: @Red.Wave Got it. Thanks.

Comment: you are wellcome.

Comment: @Red.Wave If you look at the actual source code https://github.com/boostorg/smart_ptr/blob/aa1341a6a27bd5ceeca1ace990b9d2c76eb49247/include/boost/smart_ptr/local_shared_ptr.hpp#L120 you'll see there is no double indirection. This paragraph in the documentation is just a mental model.

Answer (score 5):

I am preparing a talk on shared_ptr at work. I have been using a modified boost shared_ptr with avoid separate malloc (like what make_shared can do) and a template param for lock policy like shared_ptr_unsynchronized mentioned above. I am using the program from

http://flyingfrogblog.blogspot.hk/2011/01/boosts-sharedptr-up-to-10-slower-than.html

as a test, after cleaning up the unnecessary shared_ptr copies. The program uses the main thread only and the test argument is shown. The test env is a notebook running linuxmint 14. Here is the time taken in seconds:

```
test run setup    boost(1.49)      std with make_shared     modified boost
mt-unsafe(11)         11.9         9/11.5(-pthread on)          8.4  
atomic(11)            13.6            12.4                     13.0  
mt-unsafe(12)        113.5         85.8/108.9(-pthread on)     81.5  
atomic(12)           126.0           109.1                    123.6
```

Only the 'std' version uses -std=cxx11, and the -pthread likely switches lock_policy in g++ __shared_ptr class.

From these numbers, I see the impact of atomic instructions on code optimization. The test case does not use any C++ containers, but `vector<shared_ptr<some_small_POD>>` is likely to suffer if the object doesn't need the thread protection. Boost suffers less probably because the additional malloc is limiting the amount of inlining and code optimizaton.

I have yet to find a machine with enough cores to stress test the scalability of atomic instructions, but using std::shared_ptr only when necessary is probably better.