# Immutable/Mutable Collections in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, immutability, mutable

I was referring to Apple's Swift programming guide for understanding creation of Mutable/ immutable objects(Array, Dictionary, Sets, Data) in Swift language. But I could't understand how to create a immutable collections in Swift.

I would like to see the equivalents in Swift for the following in Objective-C

**Immutable Array**

```
NSArray *imArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"First",@"Second",@"Third",nil];
```

**Mutable Array**

```
NSMutableArray *mArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"First",@"Second",@"Third",nil];
[mArray addObject:@"Fourth"];
```

**Immutable Dictionary**

```
NSDictionary *imDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Value1", @"Key1", @"Value2", @"Key2", nil];
```

**Mutable Dictionary**

```
NSMutableDictionary *mDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Value1", @"Key1", @"Value2", @"Key2", nil];
[mDictionary setObject:@"Value3" forKey:@"Key3"];
```

Answer (score 120, accepted):

## Arrays

**Create immutable array**

First way:

```
let array = NSArray(array: ["First","Second","Third"])
```

Second way:

```
let array = ["First","Second","Third"]
```

**Create mutable array**

```
var array = ["First","Second","Third"]
```

**Append object to array**

```
array.append("Forth")
```

## Dictionaries

**Create immutable dictionary**

```
let dictionary = ["Item 1": "description", "Item 2": "description"]
```

**Create mutable dictionary**

```
var dictionary = ["Item 1": "description", "Item 2": "description"]
```

**Append new pair to dictionary**

```
dictionary["Item 3"] = "description"
```

[<sub>***More information on Apple Developer***</sub>](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html)

Comment: "Fixed length" array would be more precise. It's not immutable.

Comment: immutable `Dictionary` is truly immutable (opposite to Array)

Comment: @BryanChen Yep, I forgot to remove `var`.

Comment: Yup. More info on the un-immutability of arrays in [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24090741/300836).

Comment: `array += "Forth"` no long work in Xcode 6 GM change it to `array += ["Forth"]` or `array.append("Forth")`

Answer (score 36):

Swift does not have any drop in replacement for `NSArray` or the other collection classes in Objective-C.

There are array and dictionary classes, but it should be noted these are "value" types, compared to NSArray and NSDictionary which are "object" types.

The difference is subtle but can be very important to avoid edge case bugs.

In swift, you create an "immutable" array with:

```
let hello = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

And a "mutable" array with:

```
var hello = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Mutable arrays can be modified just like `NSMutableArray`:

```
var myArray = ["a", "b", "c"]

myArray.append("d") // ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

However you can't pass a mutable array to a function:

```
var myArray = ["a", "b", "c"]

func addToArray(myArray: [String]) {
  myArray.append("d") // compile error
}
```

But the above code does work with an NSMutableArray:

```
var myArray = ["a", "b", "c"] as NSMutableArray

func addToArray(myArray: NSMutableArray) {
  myArray.addObject("d")
}

addToArray(myArray)

myArray // ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

You can achieve `NSMutableArray`'s behaviour by using an `inout` method parameter:

```
var myArray = ["a", "b", "c"]

func addToArray(inout myArray: [String]) {
  myArray.append("d")
}

addToArray(&myArray)

myArray // ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

***Re-wrote this answer 2015-08-10 to reflect the current Swift behaviour.***

Comment: This has obviously been changed now. A constant array is now truly immutable, and a variable array is now truly mutable. They are passed as *values*, therefore they will be copied when assigned to another variable or passed between functions. This, however, has nothing to do with mutability or immutability.

Comment: Also as I mentioned in my answer, being passed as values is relevant to mutability/immutability since the only time you care about that is when passing an array to other code (which may modify it).

Comment: But if you access the array as a property, you can still modify it from another object. One of the benefits of an immutable array, is that you can safely pass it to another object, without worrying whether the other object might modify the original. This concern doesn't exist anymore when the objects are passed as values. So, different semantics require different coding practices. EDIT: I now see you have reworded the post, so we agree. I agree the differences are important to be aware of wrt. the use of mutable collections.

Answer (score 6):

There is only one `Array` and one `Dictionary` type in Swift. The mutability depends on how you construct it:

```
var mutableArray = [1,2,3]
let immutableArray = [1,2,3]
```

i.e. if you create an assign to a variable it is mutable, whereas if you create an assign to constant it is not.

**WARNING:** Immutable arrays are not entirely immutable! You can still change their contents, just not their overall length!

Comment: FYI: the array behavior is changing in an upcoming beta; I think everyone piled on about that one

Comment: @xenadu Source? ETA on that beta?

Comment: Sorry, no source. It came from a discussion with one of the compiler team members. He also said Beta 2 was basically only a couple of already checked in bug fixes and has nothing related to the post-WWDC feedback.

Answer (score 5):

Just declare your (any)object or variable with

```
'let' key word -> for "constan/Immutable" array, dictionary, variable, object..etc.
```

and

```
'var' key word -> for "Mutable" array, dictionary, variable, object..etc.
```

For more deeply information

> “Use **let** to make a constant and **var** to make a variable. The value of a constant doesn’t need to be known at compile time, but you must assign it a value exactly once. This means you can use constants to name a value that you determine once but use in many places."

```
var myVariable = 42
myVariable = 50
let myConstant = 42
```

[Read “The Swift Programming Language.”](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_399)

Comment: Well, in the case of an Array this doesn't work as expected. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24319712/623710

Answer (score 3):

If you want to work with `Array` (Swift) as with `NSArray`, you can use a simple bridge function. Example:

```
var arr1 : Array = []

arr1.bridgeToObjectiveC().count
```

It works the same for `let`.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's own docs:

> Mutability of Collections
>
> If you create an array, a set, or a dictionary and assign it to a
>   variable, the collection that is created will be mutable. This means
>   that you can change (or mutate) the collection after it is created by
>   adding, removing, or changing items in the collection. Conversely, if
>   you assign an array, a set, or a dictionary to a constant, that
>   collection is immutable, and its size and contents cannot be changed.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105

Other uses of immutable/mutable collections depend on why you want them to be mutable/immutable. Collections are *value* types in Swift, which means their contents is copied when they are assigned to another value, or passed to another function/method. Therefore, you do not need to worry about whether a receiving method function might change the original array. Therefore you don't need to ensure to return an immutable collection if your class is holding a mutable collection, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift Mutable/Immutable collection**

[[Unmodifiable and Immutable]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62935284/4770877)

Swift's array can be muted

[[let vs var, Value vs Reference Type]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59219124/4770877)

Immutable collection[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62935284/4770877) - is a collection structure of which can not be changed. It means that you can not add, remove, modify after creation

`let + struct`(like `Array`, `Set`, `Dictionary`) is more suitable to be immutable

There are some classes(e.g. `NSArray`) which **doesn't** provide an interface to change the inner state

**but**

```
class A {
    var value = "a"
}

func testMutability() {
    //given
    let a = A()
    
    let immutableArr1 = NSArray(array: [a])
    let immutableArr2 = [a]
    
    //when
    a.value = "aa"
    
    //then
    XCTAssertEqual("aa", (immutableArr1[0] as! A).value)
    XCTAssertEqual("aa", immutableArr2[0].value)
}
```

It would rather is `unmodifiable` array