# Immutable Dictionary value change

Tags: swift

Can we change any pair value in let type Dictionary in Swift Langauage.

like :

```
let arr2 : AnyObject[] = [1, "23", "hello"]
arr2[1] = 23  
arr2 // output: [1,23,"hello"]


let arr1 :Dictionary<Int,AnyObject> = [1: "One" , 2 : 2]
arr1[2] = 4 // not posible error
arr1
```

In Case of Immutable Array we can change its value like above but not in case of Immutable 
Dictionary. Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096096/immutable-mutable-collections-in-swift/24096192#24096192. It is not a dupe, simply it has some useful info.

Comment: The bottom line answer is that Apple has chosen a very bad and inconsistent definition of "immutable" when it comes to Array, and that inconsistent definition is, for better or worse, not carried over to Dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

This is taken from The Swift Programming Language book:

> For dictionaries, immutability also means that you cannot replace the
>   value for an existing key in the dictionary. An immutable dictionary’s
>   contents cannot be changed once they are set.
>
> Immutability has a slightly different meaning for arrays, however. You
>   are still not allowed to perform any action that has the potential to
>   change the size of an immutable array, but you are allowed to set a
>   new value for an existing index in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Array declared with `let` has only immutable length. Contents can still be changed.
Dictionary declared with `let` is completely immutable, you can't change contents of it. If you want, you must use `var` instead of `let`.

Answer (score 1):

Swift has changed a lot since then.

`Array` and `Dictionary` are value types. When declared with let, they cannot change any more. Especially, one cannot re-assign them, or the elements in them.

But if the type of the elements is reference type, you can change the properties of the elements in `Array` or `Dictionary`.

Here is a sample.(run in Xcode6 beta-6)

```
class Point {
    var x = 0
    var y = 0
}

let valueArr: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let refArr: [Point] = [Point(), Point()]

valueArr[0] = -1 // error
refArr[0] = Point() // error
refArr[0].x = 1

let valueDict: [Int : Int] = [1: 1, 2: 2]
let refDict: [Int: Point] = [1: Point(), 2: Point()]
valueDict[1] = -1 //error
refDict[1] = Point() //error
refDict[1]!.x = -1
```