# "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" when trying to create a new variable to be able to append an array

Tags: swift

I am new to coding and Swift and am now trying to create a small app. I created this part of code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    var selectedSubject = toBeAddedSubjects[indexPath.row] as Subject
    selectedSubject.name = cell.nameLabel
    selectedSubject.semester = cell.semesterLabel

    if cell?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark {
    cell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None;

    } else {
    cell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark;
    selectedCellsData.append(newElement: selectedSubject)
    }
    }
```

I am now getting the error

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

for `cell.nameLabel` and `cell.semesterLabel`. These, however, have already been used in a previous piece of code:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AddSubjectCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SubjectCell

    let subject = Subjects[indexPath.row] as Subject
    let Semester = "\(subject.semester)"

    cell.nameLabel.text = subject.name

    cell.semesterLabel.text = "Semester " + Semester

    return cell

}
```

It is my goal to make the append function at the end of the first code work, thus, I need to transform the cell information into the correct type for `selectedSubject`.

```
var selectedCellsData = [ Subject(name: "Initial Subject", semester: 0)]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and nice first post. As an FYI, I added some minor formatting changes to your inline code (the custom on SO is to use backticks (the key next to the 1 on a US keyboard). My edits won't appear until they have been reviewed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are casting your cell as a `SubjectCell` in the second working code sample, but not in the problem code. Make sure you cast the cell to your custom class so you can access your custom properties!

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! SubjectCell
```

Also, you are assigning UILabels to the `name` and `semester` properties of your `Subject`. Do you mean to assign the text of those labels?

```
selectedSubject.name = cell.nameLabel.text
selectedSubject.semester = cell.semesterLabel.text
```

Comment: Thank you! I now changed the casting. Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do, though the second label is an Int. My current problem is the append function. The sense behind it all is that the selectedSubject data flow into a new dataset and I want to integrate this data set into another. This I am now trying to do with 'subjectsData.append(selectedCellsData)'. The 'subjectsData' dataset has the same structure as 'selectedCellsData' (structure posted above). But I always receive the error "Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '([Subject])'. Do you have an idea what's to do?

Comment: In addition to my first comment, the updated code to collect the data for selectedCellsData: 'selectedSubject.name = cell.nameLabel.text!' and 'selectedSubject.semester = cell.semesterNumberLabel.text!.toInt()!'

Comment: It sounds like `subjectsData` and `selectedCellsData` may not be compatible types. What are the types of these? Where are they defined?

Comment: Make sure that your array is a Mutable array, otherwise you won't be able to add to it

Comment: `var subjectsData = [ Subject(name: "Investments", semester: 1), Subject(name: "Statistics", semester: 1), Subject(name: "Studium Universale", semester: 2) ]`                        and                  `var selectedCellsData = [ Subject(name: "Initial Subject", semester: 0)]`

Comment: Those are both normal NSArrays, you need NSMutableArrays to allow for appending. Try declaring them as NSMutableArrays and building them that way

Comment: But aren't they already mutable due to the `var`? NSMutableArray is objective c, isn't it? So this is not applied to Swift as Swift already includes mutable in `var`or did I misunderstood this?

Comment: You still need to declare it as an NSMutableArray I believe. Var makes it a variable while let makes it a constant, but that doesn't affect the type of the property.

Comment: according to this link ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096096/immutable-mutable-collections-in-swift ) `var` is already the swift equivalent to `NSMutableArray *myArray`.

Comment: Well I am mistaken. Sorry about that, guess I need to do some reading myself.

Comment: I would suggest making a separate question or updating for just the append issue you're having, since at least part of your problem was solved. That way it's more focused, it's technically a separate issue.