# Modifying content of immutable array in Swift does not work

Tags: swift, swift-playground

Silly beginner Swift question:
I am expecting the following 3 lines of code to work in the playground:

```
let items = ["Apple", "Orange", "Pear"]
items[1] = "Banana" // error here
items
```

Now the error

```
error: '@lvalue $T5' is not identical to 'String'
items[1] = "Banana"
```

My understanding that updating content of *immutable* array is possible in Swift.
I use XCODE 6.1.1

Any idea what is going on here?

Thanks

Based on this thread this was possible in previous releases:
[Why in immutable array in swift value can be changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292027/why-in-immutable-array-in-swift-value-can-be-changed)

Comment: Immutable usually means read only, I'm not sure why you would be able to mutate (write to) an immutable array

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html - "if you assign an array or a dictionary to a constant, that array or dictionary is immutable, and its size and contents cannot be changed."

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?isInPurchasedView=true&mt=11

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you create an immutable array in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090741/how-do-you-create-an-immutable-array-in-swift)

Comment: When Swift was first released, the elements of an immutable array could still be changed as long as you didn't change the length of the array.  At some point Apple bowed to the dictates of sanity and reversed that decision, making immutable arrays, truly immutable.

Comment: @MishaBirman, did my answer below help you?

Comment: @MishaBirman, in that case, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `let`, you define an immutable variable. Use `var` instead; this lets you define a variable that is mutable.

Answer (score 1):

as stated before me- use a `var` array  if you wish to change your array.

a bit below the question you posted a link and an answer was given inside:

> Array in Swift has been completely redesigned to have full value
>   semantics like Dictionary and String have always had in Swift.  This
>   resolves various mutability problems – now a 'let' array is completely
>   immutable, and a 'var' array is completely mutable – composes properly
>   with Dictionary and String, and solves other deeper problems.  Value
>   semantics may be surprising if you are used to NSArray or C arrays: a
>   copy of the array now produces a full and independent copy of all of
>   the elements using an efﬁcient lazy copy implementation.  This is a
>   major change for Array, and there are still some performance issues to
>   be addressed.  Please see the Swift Programming Language for more
>   information.  (17192555)

Answer (score 0):

The use of the `let` keyword declares a **Constant**.
By definition, a constant cannot be modified.

You want to use the `var` keyword to declare a **Variable**,
hence things that will/may vary.

From the apple [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309) documentation:

> Constants and Variables
>
> Constants and variables associate a name (such as
>   maximumNumberOfLoginAttempts or welcomeMessage) with a value of a
>   particular type (such as the number 10 or the string "Hello"). The
>   value of a constant cannot be changed once it is set, whereas a
>   variable can be set to a different value in the future.
>
> Declaring Constants and Variables
>
> Constants and variables must be declared before they are used. You
>   declare constants with the let keyword and variables with the var
>   keyword. Here’s an example of how constants and variables can be used
>   to track the number of login attempts a user has made:
>
> let maximumNumberOfLoginAttempts = 10
>
> var currentLoginAttempt = 0