# let Non-mutable array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

*let* type variable are supposed to be constants, but reassign a value later does not throw any error.

How do I create a non-mutable array.

```
  let testArray = ["Catfish","water","tulips"]
  print(testArray[1])
  testArray[1] = "bottle of water"
  print(testArray[1])
```

The output is "waterbottle of water"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you create an immutable array in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090741/how-do-you-create-an-immutable-array-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't reassinging the array itself, but an element of the array. This is allowed in Swift. There isn't currently a way to make all of the elements in the array immutable. It should be changed in a [future update](https://devforums.apple.com/message/989920#989920) though.

You may also want to take a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-XID_109). Arrays have interesting assignment and copying behavior in Swift.