# Swift: What does it mean when you combine NSMutable- with let?

Tags: swift

In Swift, the `let` keyword denotes immutability. What does it mean to the compiler why you combine `let` and `NSMutable`?

e.g.

```
let nsArray: NSMutableArray = ["a", "b"];
nsArray.addObject("c")  // Still works
```

Comment: Classes are *reference types*, thefore `nsArray.addObject("c")` does not change the value of `nsArray`.

Answer (score 3):

`NSMutableArray` is a class so it's passed by reference, not by value: here what is constant is your `nsArray` object, not the mutable array it contains.

So you *can* do:

```
nsArray.addObject("c")
```

But you *can't* do:

```
nsArray = ["d", "e"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. This is because you're not assigning the array itself. If you instead did:

```
nsArray = ["a", "sb"]
```

Then you would get a compiler error. This is somewhat related to the discussion here: [let Non-mutable array in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24476914/let-non-mutable-array-in-swift)