# Is it possible to append a new object to a heterogenous array in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, ios8

I know that true mutability can not be achieved in [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090741/how-do-you-create-an-immutable-array-in-swift). I have an array interspersed  with different types of contents.

```
let myArray = String[]();
var array = ["First","Second","Third",1,0.4,myArray,"dsaa"]
```

I learned from the above post I have linked that we will be able to append items to an array. But each time I add a new item to the array I have declared above I get this error:

> could not find an overload for '+=' that accepts the supplied
> arguments

But when the array is homogeneous, I am able to add an item which is same as the already present items, without hassle. but still the item with a different type can not be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare your second array explicitly as AnyObject[], you can do it:

```
let myArray = String[]()
var array:AnyObject[] = ["First", "Second", "Third", 1, 0.4, myArray, "dsaa"]
let n1 = array.count // 7
array += "next"
let n2 = array.count // 8
```