# Why can I alter the members of a const array in Swift?

Tags: swift

Why does the following code work? Trying to seek clarity around how Swift treats consts.

```
let list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list[1] = 0
```

EDIT: This is a dup of [Is there a reason that Swift array assignment is inconsistent (neither a reference nor a deep copy)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081009/is-there-a-reason-that-swift-array-assignment-is-inconsistent-neither-a-referen)

I need to get better at searching :)

Answer (score 1):

An array being `const` in Swift is a bit unlike other things in Swift. When an array is `const`, it just means that it's *length* can't be altered, individual elements can still be changed.

Answer (score 1):

To use a C equivalent, `list` is like a 'constant pointer to a non-constant object'. That means that you cannot change the array that `list` points to, but you can change its contents.