# why does msdn visual studio profiler show RtlLeaveCriticalsection and RtlEnterCriticalSection as the functions doing most individual work?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, stl

I am profiling a code that uses C++11 and STL features heavily. I have many `shared_ptr`'s and few `unique_ptr`'s. The code is serial, however when I profile the code, `RtlLeaveCriticalsection` and `RtlEnterCriticalsection` show up as the functions doing most individual work (Exclusive sample 5% each).

My thought was these internal routines invoked only for multi-threaded applications, and if there is a way to turn it off without changing the code behavior to gain performance, I would like to be able to do so.

Any suggestions or insights are appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129263/is-there-a-non-atomic-equivalent-of-stdshared-ptr-and-why-isnt-there-one-in