# Why there is no no-synchronous smart pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I've read that using `std::shared_ptr` is bad practice, because it's slow, as it has ref_counter inside, which is atomic. Why there is no such smart pointer which is exactly like `std::shared_ptr`, but it is not synchronous, so ref_counter is not-thread-safe, but we will win some performance, as in some cases we don't need to care about thread-safety

Yeah, C++ do have `std::unique_ptr` but it doesn't count refs.

I know that we can omit this by passing ptr via const-ref, but it looks like a weird fix.

Comment: Related: [Is there a non-atomic equivalent of std::shared_ptr? And why isn't there one in <memory>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15129263/555045)

Comment: *"Why"*, because it was not proposed/accepted by committee.

Comment: Avoiding `shared_ptr` in single-threaded code because of the atomic refcount operations is usually a form of premature optimization. What you really should be doing is avoiding `shared_ptr` because shared ownership is *usually* unnecessary. Then, if you need shared ownership, use `shared_ptr`. And finally, if profiling shows that the atomic refcount operations consume a substantial fraction of CPU time, drop in a thread-unsafe replacement.